# button becomes transparent on hovering

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

My button component looked like this and it worked fine:

```
<Button
component={Link}
to={link}
style={{
  background: '#6c74cc',
  borderRadius: 3,
  border: 0,
  color: 'white',
  height: 48,
  padding: '0 30px',
  width: 200,
}}
//className={classes.button}
>
{text}
</Button>
```

However, now I am trying to move from inline styles to this:

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    button: {
      background: '#6c74cc',
        borderRadius: 3,
        border: 0,
        color: 'white',
        height: 48,
        padding: '0 30px', 
        width: 200,        
    },
  }),
);
```

Now when I hover over my button, it becomes transparent/translucent. Even though the styling is the same as before. How can I stop this?

Comment: Could you please create a codepen or stackblitz(https://stackblitz.com/) so that we can help accurately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `makeStyles` and `createStyles` overrides the theme of the desired component, like a `Button`, `Text` etc.

You can do this savely by overriding the `root` of the component. Otherwise the button will keep the default `root` theme and *clashes* so to say with your styles. Which in your case would be the hover effect.

Using an inline style as you had before is equivalent to the following two examples. Which one you will use is up to you, but the first one overrides the `root` and the second implements a custom `hover` effect using the `classes.button` object:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(createStyles({
    root: {
      background: "#6c74cc",
      borderRadius: 3,
      border: 0,
      color: "white",
      height: 48,
      padding: "0 30px",
      width: 200
    }
  })
);

export default function StackOverflowDemo() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hello Sandbox!</Button>;
}
```

As an alternative solution you could add the hover effect yourself inside the "button" object like the following:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    button: {
      background: "#6c74cc",
      borderRadius: 3,
      border: 0,
      color: "white",
      height: 48,
      padding: "0 30px",
      width: 200,
      "&:hover": {
        background: "red", // <- add here your desired color, for demonstration purposes I chose red
      }
    }
  })
);

export default function StackOverflowDemo() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return <Button className={classes.button}>Hello Sandbox!</Button>;
}
```

Notice the `&:hover` syntax? This is `JSS` syntax which Material-UI includes.
A good reading starting point would be:

- [Material UI - Styles Documentation - Included JSS Plugins](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#jss-plugins)
- [CSS in JS](https://cssinjs.org/react-jss?v=v10.3.0)

Comment: there's another case where when the button is disabled, the correct color of text is not shown. How can I fix this?

Comment: you can fix this by using e.g.: `"&:disabled": { background: "blue", }` just like the "&:hover" approach

Answer (score 0):

Check in the dev tools where its coming from. i assume its default styling. if so - all you got to do is to override it with the style you want. in your case - if you want nothing to happen during hover add something like:

```
button:hover {
      background: '#6c74cc',
}
```

or with nesting

```
button: {
//...
"&:hover" {
background: '#6c74cc',
}
}
```